# Should I use ES6 on a node.js API due to performance reasons?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

Given that V8 execution of ES6 code is slower on some operations, compared to ES5.

According to this: http://incaseofstairs.com/six-speed/

Can anyone point to an article/paper/post where tests were performed in order to find out if such performance difference will impact in the normal operation of an API developed with node.js?

Comment: What evidence/data do you have that an ES6 Javascript engine is slower than an ES5 Javascript engine and which specific operations are you looking at?  In the six-speed charts you linked to, there seem to be plenty of ES6 operations that are faster.

Comment: It's not the engine itself, but rather the parsing(?) of either ES6 or ES5. In this link you can check what I'm talking about: http://incaseofstairs.com/six-speed/

Comment: Initial parsing of Javascript code for a server is usually meaningless as it only affects server startup time, not actual run-time as the code is already parsed at run-time.  Which particular operations in that chart are you focusing on?  I'm not yet sure you're looking at something that matters or is consequential.  Some of those comparisons don't make a lot of sense because you can't compare the `class` implementation in ES5 and ES6 since there is no `class` syntax implementation in ES5.

Comment: Nothing in particular really, like I said in the original question, is rather a question of whether, even with those performance hits,  should we use ES6 on a node.js API?

Comment: It's also worth noting that it's a lot more common that the performance bottlenecks in servers are not about code execution time, but are about I/O operations (database, files, etc...).  That's why we're able to build great performing servers in an interpreted language and why we aren't all writing servers in C++.

Comment: Also,  I can honestly say that I spent at least 1 hour researching for an answer, both here and on the interwebs.

Comment: Yes, you should use ES6 on a node.js API.  Once you have an implementation at scale, you can determine if you have any performance issues and profile them to find out what should best be improved.  It's unlikely that anything near the top will be ES6 feature performance of the interpreter that can be made meaningfully better with ES5.

Comment: If you happen to have some tight loop of code that's doing something very CPU intensive (something like heavy image processing), you will want to get that processing out of the main Javascript thread anyway, whether you're in ES5 or ES6 as that's one key to scaling node.js processes (getting CPU intensive operations out of the main loop).  They can either be moved to worker processes or written as an add-on in C++ and use threads.

Comment: Voted to close as "unclear what you're asking", as you said my answer below which takes your question point-for-point and answers it didn't answer your question.  If that answer doesn't help you, then I don't have any idea what you're trying to ask.

Comment: You appear to have several false premises in your question: 1) That ES6 is slower than ES5 as a general tool, 2) That this isn't premature optimization - because it most certainly is. 3) That the version of ESx will even be relevant to the bottlenecks in your API performance at scale.  4) If raw language execution speed is critically relevant to your performance, then the relevant code shouldn't be in Javascript anyway so ESx is irrelevant for that.

Comment: Damn. I actually have a non-opinion based answer to this. The outline of my answer is that this is an n+1 question (there's 26 separate questions in this question plus one general question). For the +1 case the decision to avoid all ES6 feature or use any ES6 feature depends more on what you want to target than performance. If you are targeting ES5 engines then don't target ES6...

Comment: @slebetman In this case, this person has ES6 engines, so that side of it isn't an issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: ... for the other 26 separate questions.. the consideration of weather or not you should use a language feature is on a case-by-case basis. From personal experience I can confirm that generators are slower and use more RAM than a closure based solution. If you can solve it using closures then avoid generators for speed. Most of the other features have zero performance penalty so it's up to you weather or not you want to use a feature

Comment: ... the same is true for even ES1 feature. For example javascript has a keyword called `with` that you should avoid using because it's behavior is buggy. It doesn't mean you should stop developing javascript completely because no version of javascript is without this feature and write desktop apps

Answer (score 3):

> Should I use ES6 or greater to build a node.js API, considering it is slower to ES5?

That's a false premise right off the bat, as demonstrated by the chart you linked to.

> No, this is not "premature optimization"

Yes, it is.  Choice of language dialect is much more about ease of development, compatibility with libraries, and reliability.  There is nothing in common implementations of ES6 that are "slower" across the board.  You haven't even built your application yet, and you're worried about something that is unlikely to make a significant impact at all.

If you find that there some particular code that could be optimized, Node.js allows you to implement native binaries where you can optimize all you want.

> I know some may wonder, if the API is going to get millions of hits, but again, I'm more interested in the correct pattern to use.

Use ES6.

> In the back-end, we're talking about hundreds or thousands of clients, and that performance hit will be compounded.

And yet, you don't even know what the pain points are in your application because you haven't built it yet.  For most applications, it's going to come down to I/O.

Comment: I don't see why get bashed while trying to research for a good architectural starting point, that I clearly don't see posted anywhere else. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JoseDuque Bashed?  Not sure where you're getting that... I'm directly answering your questions...

Comment: Sadly, this does not answer the question :(

Comment: Any time optimization is considered a primary factor in the decision of the implementation before a single line is written is premature. +1

Comment: @JoseDuque How does this not answer the question?  I literally took your question point-by-point and answered each of them.

Comment: Perhaps it was poorly worded, I did add a couple of edits in order to make it clearer. I'm looking for some sort of guideline, research, articles with proper benchmark tests  that indicate if there's something to worry about or nothing at all.

Comment: @JoseDuque Ah, well Stack Overflow is a place for solving problems, not having someone find off-site resources for you.  Such a question would be off-topic here.  In any case, you linked to a pretty good breakdown of performance for general methods and test cases.  Beyond that, you won't find anything, because such a test is **completely pointless and a waste of time** because it's only relevant for your specific application and how you use these tools.  Build your app and then profile it.  No, there's nothing in the JavaScript core that's going to trip you up, perf-wise between ES5/6.

Comment: @JoseDuque Suppose you're going to build a go-kart.  You can buy aluminum tubes for the frame in both metric and US imperial units.  "Which one will make a faster go-kart?", you ask.  Wrong question.  Maybe think more about that when designing the frame, picking an engine, and placing wheels.

Comment: @brad ahhh I see, I was kinda hoping to find that, and have a good reference to rely on.